# Why my Displacement modifier is not working?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I am following this tutorial, and when I apply the displacement modifier, I get this result:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Has the modifier changed? Because I am doing exactly what the guy is doing but my modifier is changing and distorting the fruit in a weird way. Using the latest version. I want the fruit to be more like a fruit, not as round as a ball.

Comment: difficult to say, without having model and texture, but: check scale applying, normals and texture settings, as a minimum...

Comment: Afaik modifier wasn't changed that much. Check that the mesh is subdivided evenly (you might want to show mesh in Edit mode without any modifiers) and maybe [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) the object and include link here.

Comment: I found the solution. Go to the displacement tab and select cloud texture instead of Image texture. :)